# Calling stopListening on window unload for all views?

Tags: javascript, marionette, backbone-views

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension which consists of a temporary foreground page and a permanent background page.

Views in the foreground listen to models held in the background. Eventually, the foreground window is unloaded, but the background's models persist. So, I need to ensure that all foreground views call stopListening whenever the window unloads.

My current solution is a bit sloppy and manual. I've implemented a ForegroundViewManager model:

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var ForegroundViewManager = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: function () {
            return {
                views: []
            };
        },

        initialize: function() {
            $(window).unload(function () {
                this.allViewsStopListening();
            }.bind(this));
        },

        allViewsStopListening: function() {
            _.each(this.get('views'), function(view) {
                view.stopListening();
            });
        },

        subscribe: function (view) {
            var views = this.get('views');
            var index = views.indexOf(view);

            if (index === -1) {
                views.push(view);
            }
        },

        unsubscribe: function (view) {
            var views = this.get('views');
            var index = views.indexOf(view);

            if (index > -1) {
                views.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }

    });

    return new ForegroundViewManager();
});
```

and then I make sure to call subscribe in every view's initialize:

```
define([
    'foreground/model/foregroundViewManager'
], function (ForegroundViewManager) {
    'use strict';

    var ExampleItemView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            ForegroundViewManager.subscribe(this);
        }

    });

    return ExampleItemView;
});
```

Two questions:

- Is it a good idea to be using ForegroundViewManager? Should every view bind to window.unload individually instead of having a manager bind once and iterate over subscriptions?
- Is there a way to make calling subscribe implicit?

Comment: What are you using to communicate between the background page and foreground? If you are using `runtime.port`, it already has a onDisconnect event, which should fire automatically.

Comment: I'm not. I'm using chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() to reference the background window and am directly listening to models.